# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem adding delegate?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Reading through some code I found:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { this.SaveInternal(); });
```

Why would someone put `delegate` here?

Comment: Same as your last question.  Look up "anonymous method" in your favorite C# language book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious answer is because the code won't compile without it. For example:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( { this.SaveInternal(); });
```

Gives `Invalid expression term '{'`

`QueueUserWorkItem` requires a [WaitCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback.aspx) argument, which is a method that takes an `Object` parameter. The long form of what you have there is:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) => { this.SaveInternal(); });
```

Which is the same as:

```
void Temp(Object state)
{
    this.SaveInternal();
}

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Temp);
```

Adding `delegate { this.SaveInternal(); }` allows the compiler to use type inference to resolve the apparent ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

Usinng delegate like that is just a shortcut for passing any valid delegate that you don't care about the arguments while keeping the compiler happy. Otherwise you would have to pass a method that matches the delegate signature.